# What are the differences between Hierarchical drill down navigation & Hierarchical multi-level navigation

Tags: interaction-design, navigation, design-patterns, menu, terminology

What are the differences between Hierarchical drill down menu & Hierarchical multi-level menu? it seems there is a thin line between these two.

Please help me with examples which navigation model should be called as Hierarchical drill down navigation & which one is Hierarchical multi-level navigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drill down means you show only one menu at a time. It brings you further down the menu structure. An example is the iPod menu:

[image]

Or see this [working example](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/demo-wordpress-jquery-drill-down-ipod-menu-plugin/#) in jQuery.

A hierarchical multi-level menu is more like a dropdown or accordion menu where the whole submenu structure is visible:

[Accordion example](http://codepen.io/rbobrowski/pen/likvA):
[image]
Or as dropdown menu:
[image]
[An example in bootstrap](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain a little more about each?

Comment: yes of course,first image mean one node will have multiple nodes but it doesn't contains any subnodes further. Whereas in second, main node will have sub node then again sub node can have child node and so on...its not necessary that each subnode will have child node. and child node can have subchild node like chain concept.